# Applescript handler/subroutine not giving same results as normal code

Tags: macos, applescript

I can't seem to figure out why this code is working fine outside of a subroutine but giving me an error when copying it into a subroutine and running it.

I've tried everything and googled for hours. Any help is appreciated.

ORIGINAL CODE

```
tell application "iTerm"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    tell application "iTerm" to activate --activate or open if closed
    tell application "iTerm" to reopen -- un-minimize if minimized
    tell application "iTerm" to set the bounds of the first window to {0, 23, 960, 1080}
end tell
```

SUBROUTINE CODE

```
on MoveWindowScripted(app2move, windowPosition) -- last step not working for some reason...
    tell application app2move
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        tell application app2move to activate --activate or open if closed
        tell application app2move to reopen -- un-minimize if minimized
        tell application app2move to set the bounds of the first window to {0, 23, 960, 1080}
    end tell
end MoveWindowScripted

MoveWindowScripted(app2, LbottomLeft)
```

I would expect to get the same results from both situations. The window should activate and move to a certain location. It works for the first code, but not for the subroutine. I get the message "Notes got an error: Can’t set application "Notes" to {0, 23, 960, 1080}." However, when I update the subroutine and replace this line "tell application app2move to set the bounds of the first window to {0, 23, 960, 1080}" with this "tell application "Notes" to set the bounds of the first window to {0, 23, 960, 1080}", it works fine.

Comment: Do you understand how AppleScript works? Everything depends on the scriptability and dictionary of each individual app. There are no universals. Every app is its own special case.

Comment: You do not need the `tell application "iTerm" to` or `tell application app2move to` when the target _commands_ are already wrapped in a `tell application "iTerm"` or `tell application app2move` _block_. Also, in `MoveWindowScripted(app2, LbottomLeft)` Both `app2` and `LbottomLeft` are not defined. -- Removing the three unnecessary `tell application app2move to` and calling the _handler_ with `MoveWindowScripted("Notes", missing value)` works fine for me.

Comment: @user3439894 — you should post that as an answer...

Comment: Thanks @user3439894, That did the trick! I should spend more time learning this language. I appreciate your time and your answer. If you want some credit, post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer @user3439894.

You do not need the `tell application "iTerm" to` or t`ell application app2move to` when the target *commands* are already wrapped in a `tell application "iTerm"` or `tell application app2move` block. Removing the three unnecessary `tell application app2move to` and calling the handler with `MoveWindowScripted("Notes", missing value)` works fine for me.